# detecting missing jpegs over the internet

Tags: java, url

The problem my application reads in jpegs and displays them on a jlabel (these are pictures of books)
Everything works fine when used with the local version e.g. reading from the C drive, but once I try to do this over the internet problems occur that I have tried without success to correct
Scenario 
Should the jpeg not be present at the end of the url  I get the following error

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
```

In the version that reads from the local drive I detect if the file exist and overcome this problem however I have tried lots of the ideas posted and I simply can’t find out how to detect that the jpeg is absent!
Please can some one help
here are the two version of the code

Read from local drive C

```
private void showcover() {
    String stockPic;
    String partofISBN;
    String completeurl;
    jButton9.setVisible(true);
    stockPic = jTextField1.getText();// get the current isbn
    partofISBN = stockPic.substring(0, 7); // get first 7 numbers
    String picUrl;
    stockPic = stockPic + localNumber + ".jpg";
    picUrl = partofISBN + "\\" + stockPic;
    completeurl = "C:\\Apicture\\" + picUrl;

    File pf = new File(completeurl);

    if (!pf.exists()) {

        jLabel9.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Apicture\\" + picUrl));
        jLabel9.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Apicture\\nojpegs.jpg"));
        jLabel9.setText("NO Jpeg");
    }

    jLabel9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(completeurl));

}
```

Adaption to read from url

```
URL url;
url = new URL("http://ebid.s3.amazonaws.com/upload_big/9/1/1/1401018425-17770-385.jpg");

Image image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(baseframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(baseframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Read up on Try/Catch - you can respond to the exception and handle it instead of crashing.  You can start reading here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Comment: this may very well be just a network-related problem. make sure your app can connect to the internet (firewall, proxy, etc).

Answer (score 0):

`javax.imageio.IIOException` means your are not getting the image.

So add more code to failover to alternate URL/disk in your `catch(IOException )` block.

Answer (score 0):

Read http HEAD request and response code 404 for not found. Http is your friend.

Find out of the resource exists before you GET it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this answer I just provided: [I can't download a specific image using java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317978/i-cant-download-a-specific-image-using-java-code/24318174#24318174)

Seems like amazon is also checking your user-agent, so you may have to put something like this **at the beginning of your code**:

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
```

edit: "*at the beginning of your code*" really means something like "*before creating any URL-related object*". I mean, I didn't want to refer to the code you posted, but you whole application.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
URL url;
url = new URL("http://ebid.s3.amazonaws.com/upload_big/9/1/1/1401018425-17770-385.jpg");
url.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");

Image image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(baseframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(baseframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```